# Get all days of the months from specific day using momentJS in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I trying to create a 'static' custom day picker that will show all the days of the month in a calendar view, I want to display all the dates of the selected month from Sunday to Saturday. The result that i getting now is all the dates from the 1st to the month

[image]

```
  getDaysArrayByMonth() {
    this.monthSwitched = !this.monthSwitched;
    this.daysOfSelectedMonth = [];
    this.monthDaysAmount = moment(this.selectedMonth, 'MMMM YYYY').daysInMonth();
    const remainingToEvenRows = 35 - this.monthDaysAmount;
    const days = this.monthDaysAmount + remainingToEvenRows;
    for (let i = 0; i < days; i++) {
      this.daysOfSelectedMonth.push(moment(this.selectedMonth, 'MMMM YYYY').month(this.selectedMonth).date(i + 1).format('l'));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            function getDaysInMonth(date) {
                date = date.startOf('month');
                let month = date.month();
                let days = [];
                while (date.month() === month) {
                    days.push(moment(date));
                    date.add(1, 'days')
                }
                return days;
            }
```